# Installing PHP-GTK with PHP 5.3 on OS X

Tags: php, mac-osx

I'm having trouble getting php-gtk installed with php 5.3 on os x. I'm currently using macports to do it and when I try to install php-gtk, it spews 'duplicate static' errors:

```
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_php_php5-gtk/work/php-gtk-2.0.1" && /usr/bin/make -j2 all " returned error 2
Command output: ext/gtk+/gen_pango.c:2951: error: duplicate 'static'
ext/gtk+/gen_pango.c:2957: error: duplicate 'static'
ext/gtk+/gen_pango.c:3097: error: duplicate 'static'
ext/gtk+/gen_pango.c:3103: error: duplicate 'static'
```

Is there a way to coerce it into building, or an alternative way to install it?

Comment: What's the exact MacPorts command you're running?

Comment: sudo port install php5-gtk

Answer (score 1):

php-gtk2 is not supported in php 5.3. 
The [phpgtk homepage](http://gtk.php.net/) talks about how the next version will support version 5.3. On the down side, that post was posted almost two years ago. The latest post from 6 months ago says that it is still slowly being worked on.

[I've posted instruction here on how you can set up gtk on php 5.2.17 using macports](http://www.hdogtech.com)

Answer (score 0):

What version do you have of :

- PHP
- Mac OS X
- MacPorts

Maybe you should try [this installer](http://mirror.transact.net.au/sourceforge/a/project/ag/agata/agata%20for%20linux/5/PHP-GTK-2.0.0.dmg).

**EDIT :** installer link changed

Comment: Will the installer, which appears to install php 5.2.5 according to the screenshots in the link you provided, interfere with my current macports installation of php 5.3?

Comment: Actually, the [installer link](http://www.kix.in/php-gtk2/PHP-GTK-2.0.0.dmg) doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Link changed. The installer doesn't install PHP, it only installs the bindings for GTK. I download it and it installs everything in `/usr/local/php-gtk`, so it shouldn't interfere with MacPorts install which is in `/opt`

Comment: I have PHP 5.3.2 installed through macports 1.8.2 running on OS X 10.6.2

Comment: Try updating MacPorts to its latest version : 1.9.1 (at the time of writing)